# How to find 1-month overlap of sequential contracts using SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with contract dates:
[image]

The visualization looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I am trying to identify the month in which an overlap between sequential contracts only is 1-month long. With this logic, we could flag Jan-21 as such month.

How would I compile that as a simple SQL statement using Snowflake?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  What format is. your date in?  I don't really see a one month overlap, because the days are different.  Please explain.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Apoogies, the aggregation will be at a month level, not day. So jan-3 and jan-4 will be both aggregated to jan, thus the sequential overlap of 1 month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best that I can tell is that you want two contracts that meet the following conditions:

- One ends and the other starts in the same calendar month.
- The two overlap by at least one day.

I would not call this "one month overlap", but this appears to be what you are describing.

If so, you can use a `join`:

```
select date_trunc('month', c1.start_date) as month_of_overlap,
       c1.*, c2.*
from contracts c1 join
     contracts c2
     on date_trunc('month', c1.start_date) = date_trunc('month', c2.end_date) and
        c1.start_date < c2.end_date;
```

Comment: But it is not always 1-day overlap, right? Jan-3 and Jan-4 are sequential, so this is also a use case. thus overlap on a month makes more use, no?

Comment: @titu84hh . . . You can remove the second condition.  It seems even stranger to say that two time periods overlap when they are completely disjoint.